# Block UITableView not scrolling , when get Facebook Friend List - ios

Tags: ios, uitableview, facebook-graph-api, scroll

I have implement a script to get list friends in my facebook include image, username....
But when it load to viewcontroller ( uitableview ) list friends has return but the tableview be block scrolling, please help

```
'- (void)getFriendsListWithCompleteBlock:(void (^)(NSArray *, NSString *))completed{

if (!FBSession.activeSession.isOpen)
{
    NSLog(@"permissions::%@",FBSession.activeSession.permissions);

    // if the session is closed, then we open it here, and establish a handler for state changes
    [FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:@[@"basic_info", @"user_friends"]
                                       allowLoginUI:YES
                                  completionHandler:^(FBSession *session,
                                                      FBSessionState state,
                                                      NSError *error) {
                                      if (error)
                                      {
                                          UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error"
                                                                                              message:error.localizedDescription
                                                                                             delegate:nil
                                                                                    cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                                                    otherButtonTitles:nil];
                                          [alertView show];
                                      }
                                      else if (session.isOpen)
                                      {
                                          [self showWithStatus:@""];
                                          FBRequest *friendRequest = [FBRequest requestForGraphPath:@"me/friends?fields=name,picture,gender"];


                                              [friendRequest startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
                                                  NSArray *data = [result objectForKey:@"data"];
                                                  NSMutableArray *friendsList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
                                                  for (FBGraphObject<FBGraphUser> *friend in data)
                                                  {
                                                      //NSLog(@"friend:%@", friend);
                                                      NSDictionary *picture = [friend objectForKey:@"picture"];
                                                      NSDictionary *pictureData = [picture objectForKey:@"data"];
                                                      //NSLog(@"picture:%@", picture);
                                                      FBData *fb = [[FBData alloc]
                                                                    initWithData:(NSString*)[friend objectForKey:@"name"]
                                                                    userID:(NSInteger)[[friend objectForKey:@"id"] integerValue]
                                                                    gender:(NSString*)[friend objectForKey:@"gender"]
                                                                    photoURL:(NSString*)[pictureData objectForKey:@"url"]
                                                                    photo:(UIImage*)nil
                                                                    isPhotoDownloaded:(BOOL)NO];
                                                      [friendsList addObject:fb];
                                                  }
                                                  NSString *message;
                                                  if (friendsList.count <1) {
                                                      message = @"Not Founds";
                                                  }

                                                  [self dismissStatus];
                                                  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                                                  if (completed) {
                                                      completed(friendsList,message);
                                                  }
                                                  });
                                              }];


                                      }
                                  }];
}
```

}
'

Comment: are tableview.scrollingEnabled and tableview.userInteractionEnabled true? userInteractionEnabled has to be true in all superviews too.

Comment: can you send me a demo.i finding so much but i did not get fb friend list